# Input Box problem In reactjs, On single click cursor is not pointing in text-box , On double click in the text-box Input Cursor is coming

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am very new to this. Below is the code, please Help

On single click Input cursor is not pointing in text-box, On double click on the text-box Input Cursor is coming. Also if I am adding a placeholder, not able to input anything.

```
   export default class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    UserID: "",
    Password: ""
  };
  UserIdchangeHandler = text => {
    this.setState({
      UserID: text.target.value
    });
  };
  PasswordchangeHandler = text => {
    this.setState({
      Password: text.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="backgroundImg">
        <span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserTie} size="lg" />
        </span>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={text => {
            this.UserIdchangeHandler(text);
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <span>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faKey} size="lg" />
        </span>
        <input
          type="password"
          onChange={text => {
            this.UserIdchangeHandler(text);
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <button>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import "./login.css";

import { library, text } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {  faUserTie, faKey, } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(faUserTie)

 export default class Login extends Component{

    state={
        UserID:"",
        Password:""
      }
    UserIdchangeHandler=(text)=>{
        this.setState({
            UserID:text.target.value
        })
    }
    PasswordchangeHandler=(pass)=>{
        this.setState({
            Password:pass.target.value
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (

 <div className="backgroundImg">
      <span>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserTie} size="lg"></FontAwesomeIcon>
      </span>
    <input type="text" onChange={(text)=>{this.UserIdchangeHandler(text)}} ></input>
    <br/>
    <span>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faKey} size="lg"></FontAwesomeIcon>
    </span>
    <input type="password" onChange={(pass)=>{this.PasswordchangeHandler(pass)}}></input>
    <br/>
    <button>Login</button>
    </div>         

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you have onChange handler but didn't set the value in your input.

If you add a onChange handler you need to add the value prop

```
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.stateUserId}  // You're missing this here
      onChange={evt => {
        this.UserIdchangeHandler(evt);
      }}
    />
```

> You can learn more about controlled/uncontrolled on the React Docs here. In your case you're trying to create a **controlled input** 
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Side Note:
In your onChange you labeled the property `text`. But its better to call it `event`

Comment: I did the change as you suggested. Still, I have to double click on textbox if I want to start typing in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.UserID}  // you are missing value here.
    onChange={text => {
                        this.UserIdchangeHandler(text);
                      }
             }
/>
```

and same as the password input field.

Comment: I did the change as you suggested. Still, I have to double click on textbox if I want to start typing in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved now. The problem was with Css of the class. Z-index was set to lower value.Increasing the z-index helped me here.